# How to split an array in to respective elements in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy for elasticsearch scripting
I need to accomplish the following
I have an array

```
array1 = [1,2,3]
```

I need to split array1 into individual components and push those elements to another array,say array2.

EDIT:
The script I am using is like below

```
switch(identifier){
  case "single" : ctx._source[field][type].push(id);
  case "batch": for(i in id) {ctx._source[field][type].push(id[i])}
}
```

but for case "batch" I am getting error. Here "id" is the array I need to split and push.

Comment: Can you please define the desired output?

Comment: Why have you tagged elasticsearch in this question??Is this question related to elastcisearch

Comment: Actually I was trying to write a script for elasticsearch. I habitually added the tag, as I usually ask elasticsearch related questions. Will remove it. Sorry for the confusion created

Comment: You've tried `ctx._source[field][type] + id` yeah?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Opal
{"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[Exception evaluating property '695177535156518912' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: 695177535156518912 for class: java.lang.String]]; ","status":400}

Comment: @ArunMohan, it seems that it should just be: `case "batch": for(i in id) {ctx._source[field][type].push(i)}` - `i` instead of `id[i]`.

Comment: @Opal Thanks dude, It worked. Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @ArunMohanm, sure. Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
case "batch": for(i in id) {ctx._source[field][type].push(i)}
```

`i` instead of `id[i]`.

In this kind of iteration `i` is an object, not an *index*.

Comment: isn't this just `ctx._source[field][type].addAll(id)`?

Comment: May be @cfrick, don't know the context.